# Is it possible to disable the default 'pop' transition on custom select menus? (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

As in the title: Is it possible to disable the default 'pop' transition on custom select menus?

Comment: Just change the transition: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

Comment: @PhillPafford I'm invoking it programmatically

Comment: What about using native: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

Comment: @PhillPafford I can't as I'm using `$('select').selectmenu('open');` which doesn't work on native menus.

Answer (score 0):

See [global configuration options](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html) of jQuery mobile for reference:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none"; // Or whichever transition you want
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an effect on select menus transitions.